# How to reset the counter value?

Tags: php

Here is my code, I have the counter value for generating new files. I am passing unit value through ajax to php. Whenever I changed the unit value that time I want to reset the counter value. How to do it?

```
  $v=$_GET['v'];
       $project=$_GET['p'];
        $unit=$_GET['u'];
        echo $unit ;
        $a_str = array($_POST["content"]);
        $a_url = $_POST["url"];
        $contents = implode(PHP_EOL, $a_str);
        $filename = file_get_contents($project."/counter.txt");
        $counter = file_exists($project.'/counter.txt') ? file_get_contents($project."/counter.txt")+1 : 1 ;
        $contents .= PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
        file_put_contents($project."/unit-".$unit.'.'.$counter."-".$v.".html",$contents);
        file_put_contents($project."/counter.txt",$counter);
```

Comment: Where do you change unit value?

Comment: i changed the unit value through ui

Comment: Where that change in your code?

Comment: file_put_contents($project."/unit-".$unit.'.'.$counter."-".$v.".html",$contents); here it will change the unit value

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the unit value in session and compare with current value. If changed, then reset the `$counter`. Then update the session value with current value for the next cycle of test.

In above code snippet add below lines.

```
if(empty($_SESSION["cur_unit"])) //For first time, 
{
   $_SESSION["cur_unit"] = $unit;
}
```

set unit value in session

```
if($unit != $_SESSION["cur_unit"])
{
   $_SESSION["cur_unit"] = $unit;
   //reset the counter value here
}
```

Note: Don't forget to add line `session_start();` at beginning of this page.

Comment: thanks,when ever i changed the unit value my session unit value and getting unit value are same,it's not workig..

Comment: I think you have misplaced first line. Better remove my first line.check my updated answer